# Creating a virtual server

Tags: python, server, cloud, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a virtual server, i am really new to this so I over think the little stuff.

Basically this is the information I am working with

this is the hardware config:

Name: m1 
IP: 128.0.0.1 
mem: 16gb
num_disk: 8 
num_cores 10

This is what I have and I need help trying to get it to work.

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

name = "10m1" request = Request('http://128.0.0.1/') mem = 16 num_disk
= 8 num_cores = 0 disk_bootable = True

disk_params = params.Disk(name, request, mem, num_disk, num_cores)   try:
      #add disk to vm here
       #print vm added
    except Exception as ex:
       #print vm failed to add

try:
    response = urlopen(request)
    answer = response.read()
     except URLError, e:
    print 'No answer. Got an error code:', e
```

Comment: Please explain what "trying to get it to work" means. What is currently not working? Also, what hypervisor are you using to do this? If you are doing this in python, you must be using an SDK that works with this hypervisor you are going to be using to manage and bring up your VMs?

Comment: There are multiple parts to this. For this part, I am just trying to create a server. Sorry, this is my first time doing something like this so i dont know most of the requirements. There are no hardware machines to use in my cloud,
so i didn't think i had to issue an hypervisor command.

Comment: How do you expect the virtual machine to start with allocated resources without some *manager*. That *is* what a hypervisor is responsible for.

Comment: How can I decided on what hypervisor to use?

Comment: There are a lot of options out there for you, especially in the open source domain. If you are looking to write code to manage virtual machines and talk to the hypervisor to do this for you, you should see which ones have that kind of SDK/API available to you. Which begs the question, your code seems to be missing some more details. For example, what is `params` in your code? It is referencing something that does not exist in your code.

Comment: oh i got that part from an online source, I basically just wanted to create parameters that my disk would have. I think I will use the KVM hypervisor for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148137/discussion-between-sa7-and-idjaw).